# Database Settings for Search Service Application

Tags: search, service

I want to avoid hiccups in my SharePoint setup, so I will like to ask what database should I specify for Search Service Application. Should I use the same database specified for my SharePoint Farm Configuration.

I am running SharePoint 2013 Server on a single server on windows 2012 datacenter edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices is that you assign those database to the same database server.
The names of the Search db's can be set when creating a new search service application and are by default prefilled. The only thing you may need to apply is a possible company policy when creating databases.

More information about a Search Service Application can be found on TechNet using the following url: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502597(v=office.15).aspx.

Comment: Hi hevling, I am using a powershell to create the Search Service Application so they are not prefilled.. so are you saying its ok to use the same the db that my SharePoint server is using?

Comment: Yes, the same db server.  I always look back to 2 examples which can be found on the www.  http://melcher.it/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-create-a-search-service-application-and-topology-with-powershell/  http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=378

Comment: ok, I should use the same Database Server but specify a different database Name, am I right sir?

Comment: Exactly! At the end 3 separate databases for search will be created.